# Error Logging In & Getting Facebook OAUTH Token

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

Using the Facebook SDK to get a user token and then convert it into a page access token.
However I'm getting the Unauthorised Access or error occurred.

Here is my code

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
  'app_secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v10.0',
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$permissions = ['manage_pages']; // Add additional permissions if needed

$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://your-callback-url/', $permissions); // Replace 'https://your-callback-url/' with your actual callback URL

try {
    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exception\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exception\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

if (isset($accessToken)) {
    // Logged in successfully
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

    // Get user access token
    $userAccessToken = $_SESSION['access_token'];

    // Get page access token
    $response = $fb->get('/me/accounts', $userAccessToken);
    $pages = $response->getGraphEdge()->asArray();

    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        if ($page['id'] == 'YOUR_PAGE_ID') {
            $pageAccessToken = $page['access_token'];
            break;
        }
    }

    // Use the generated page access token
    echo "Page Access Token: " . $pageAccessToken;

} else {
    // Unable to log in
    echo 'Unauthorized access or error occurred.';
}

?>
```

But yet if I define the $accessToken then the page access token is generated fine.
Any help would be appreciated because having to get the page token via the graph explorer manually multiple times daily is really bugging me

Comment: Debug both tokens, the one you "define", and the one you are getting from this process here, and check if they encompass the same permissions.

Comment: Not getting user token from the process .
Just tried echoing the accessToken value but getting blank page.
Also changes permissions to

$permissions = ['pages_show_list','page_events','pages_read_engagement','pages_read_user_content','pages_manage_posts','pages_manage_engagement'];

Comment: If I define the accessToken and use the value I get from the Graph Explorer tool it works but it wont go through login process as it should with me defining it

Comment: "Blank page" could mean that you missed an exception. Try and add a block that catches any generic one.

Comment: Just tried dumping $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken(); but nothing returned.

Comment: Right .. this is strange ..
I did var_dump($loginUrl) and copied the returned url string containing the scopes etc into the browser and the login prompt came up..

Comment: Ok so using the URL string that got dumped from the $loginURL it went through the login process and redirected ok .. but dont know why the process isnt working automatically

Comment: Because you only _created_ the `$loginUrl`, but you are not _doing_ anything with it. Your app needs to redirect the user there, when it realizes it does not currently have a valid access token.

Comment: Yeah only just spotted that as well ...
Got it working now :) thanks for the help